# how to embed facebook video in django project

Tags: python, django, video-streaming

what is the easiest way to embed facebook live video or any facebook video in any django website ?

I used https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video  package but it's work only for youtube video .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about live video but you can use  tag of html to embed it.